# $4\cosh \left(x\right)-3\sinh \left(x\right)=5$ where to start?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is: Solve this equation giving your answer to 3d.p

$4\cosh \left(x\right)-3\sinh \left(x\right)=5$

I have no idea what to use for this one

Comment: Rewrite both hyperbolic functions in terms of $e^x$, then you will get a quadratic in $e^x$. Now solve.

Comment: yeah sorted now. just needed to know the start point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4\cosh x-3\sinh x=5$$ $$4\left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\right)-3\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\right)=5$$ $$4(e^{2x}+1)-3(e^{2x}-1)=10e^{x}$$ $$(e^{x})^2-10e^{x}+7=0$$ Now, solving for $e^{x}$, we get $$e^{x}=\frac{-(-10)\pm\sqrt{(-10)^2-4(1)(7)}}{2(1)}$$ $$=\frac{10\pm6\sqrt 2}{2}=5\pm 3\sqrt 2$$ $$e^x=5+3\sqrt 2\ \ \ \vee\ \ e^x=5-3\sqrt 2$$ $$\color{blue}{x=\ln(5+3\sqrt 2)}\ \ \ \vee \ \ \ \color{blue}{x=\ln(5-3\sqrt 2)}$$

Comment: A *hint* is all that is required.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly
\begin{eqnarray}
\sinh x &=&\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} \\
\cosh x &=& \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
So your equation becomes;
$$4 \left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}
 \right)-3 \left( \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}
\right) = 5 $$
Or
$$4 \left(e^{x}+e^{-x}
 \right)-3 \left(e^{x}-e^{-x}
\right) = 10 $$
Multiplying by $e^{x}$ gives;
$$4\left(e^{2x}+1
 \right)-3 \left(e^{2x}-1
\right) = 10e^{x}$$
Now what you must do is to set $u=e^{x}$ and notice something important about the equation. You should be able to solve for $u$ then solve for $x$.

Comment: You have a $e^{3x}$ that should be $2^{2x}$... Nice done +1.

Comment: Yes, noticed that too. Fixed, many thanks.

Comment: @johannesvalks Wait, a *$2^{2x}$* - you mean $e^{2x}$ yes?

Comment: ahh I see now, however I think you have put a - in place of the + that should be there for the eqv of coshx

Comment: @joe Good spot Joe - wasn't thinking!

Comment: Yes indeed. A typo in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both of them to their exponential form and solve. 
$$4\cosh(x)-3\sinh(x)=5$$ 
$$2(e^x+e^{-x})-\frac{3(e^x-e^{-x})}{2}=5$$ 
$$4e^x+4e^{-x}-3e^x+3e^{-x}=10$$ 
$$e^x+7e^{-x}=10$$ 
Let $e^x=t$ 
$$t+\frac7t=10$$ 
$$t^2+7=10t$$ 
$$\frac{10\pm\sqrt{100-28}}{2}=t$$ 
$$\ln({5\pm6\sqrt{2}})=x$$ 
$2.602$ & other one is a complex root.